# use case class in other package in scala

Tags: scala, case-class

```
// vh.scala
class VH(temp: String) extends Serializable {
  case class car(name: String, color: String, year: Int) // case class I want to use in other package
}
```

I made class named VH, which will use in main scala

```
// main.scala
import packname.VH
val cars = nameRDD.map({ name=> car(name, "red", 2010) }).... // works well
```

til here, It's work as I wanted BUT below code is not work or compiled.

```
cars.map({ car=> tf.go( car)}) // it's what I want to do

// other.scala - tf class
import packname.VH // not work
class TF ... {
 def go( car: car) // not work
 def go( car: VH.car) // not work
}
```

How can I use case class define in other package class? Any Idea of this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `car` is a nested class, and it doesn't seem like it needs to be. Just move it outside `VH`. If it actually needs to be nested, you'll need a `VH` instance to work with it, e.g.

```
def go(vh: VH)(car: vh.car)
```

Comment: Thanks! I moved it outside of VH and everything solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
new VH("str arg whatever").car("mycar", "red", 2023)
```